# dynamically align thumbnails in a row

Tags: html, css

I have simple gallery like this:

```
<div class="gallery">

<div class="thumbnail">

    <img src="1.jpg">

</div>  

<div class="thumbnail">

    <img src="2.jpg">

</div>  

...

</div>
```

How to auto-align thumnbails in row?

First thumbnails from the row should be align to the left and last from row to the right

Margin between align should be change dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS flexbox: difference between align-items and align-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250174/css-flexbox-difference-between-align-items-and-align-content)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250174/css-flexbox-difference-between-align-items-and-align-content, where `justify-content` should either be set to `space-between` or `space-around`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: flex` on the outer box.
And use all the flex properties you need to display the inner boxes as you like.

```
.gallery{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.thumbnail{
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid gray 3px;
}
```

Live example https://jsfiddle.net/m12xcxwy/

Complete tutorial on flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: How have I lived so long without this information?!

Comment: @trex005 This is a rather recent feature of CSS3, it won't work in IE I guess but who cares

Comment: Works from IE9 onwards with vendor prefix -ms-flex.

Answer (score 2):

hi you can see if this is as per your desire

```css
.gallery{
    display:block;
}
.thumbnail{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline-block;` isn't required here to make it work

Comment: @singe3 you can work with display:inline-block but then the div with thumbnail will get the block individual if you remove then all that div's will work as a whole block

Comment: @singe3 so it's fine whether to use or not but it's the difference bdw thanx for that

Comment: @Igor checkout the answers